# PNG multiple IDAT chunks (PHP)

Tags: php, png, compression

I'm learning png IDAT chunks now. I tried writing my own code to read them, and it works fine if there is only 1 IDAT chunk, but fails when there are more "IDAT 78 DA" chunks. My question is that: What should I modify in my code and how?
Thanks for all the replies. :)

```
<?php
$in_filename = "stego15.png";

$raw_data = file_get_contents($in_filename);
$idat_chunks = explode('IDAT', substr($raw_data, 0, -4));

foreach ($idat_chunks as $idat_number=>$idat_chunk) {
    if ($idat_number==0) {
        continue;
    }
    $chunk = substr($idat_chunk, 2, -4);
    $decompressed = gzinflate($chunk);

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($in_filename);
    $data = str_split(bin2hex($decompressed), $width*6+2);
    $grouped_data = array();
    foreach ($data as $row=>$d) {
        $grouped_data[$row] = str_split(substr($d, 2), 6);
    }
    echo '<h1>'.$idat_number.'. chunk</h1>';
    var_dump($grouped_data);
}

?>
```

Comment: Yeah this is super confusing and (so far as I can tell) definitely *not* in the spec – glad to get an official answer here!

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean more "IDAT 78 DA" chunks? It is unlikely that you would see those particular bytes, a zlib header, in the 2nd or later IDAT chunks. All of the image data is compressed once, and *then* broken up into chunks. So you need to put all the IDAT data together and *then* inflate it all at once.

Comment: I try to fix in this way, but it doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/k0GZxrkk . You are right, only the first idat chunk has 78 DA. :)

Comment: "Put all the IDAT data together" means remove the length, "IDAT", and crc bytes from each IDAT chunk, concatenate the remaining contents, and pass the result to the inflator.

Comment: May you show me that? I still don't understand how. :$ Sorry. :$

Comment: We are not going to write or debug your code for you. All we can tell you is what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. :)